# Index log files using Elasticsearch

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, kibana, flume

I am new to elasticsearch. I have been searching on this for a couple of days but could not find anything related to it. Actually, I want to index log files that are coming from a spooldir through Apache Flume.

I am able to receive data in elasticsearch. But now I want the log data to be split in several fields and then get indexed. Say for example...

> "127.0.0.1 - - [18/Mar/2015:20:36:04 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 994"...this is my log data.

Now indexing should happen like...

```
 field 1 is IP address,
 field 2 is timestamp, 
 field 3 is GET or POST method,
 field 4 is protocol,
 field 5 is status code,
 field 6 is time taken
```

And then I want to visualize these fields using Kibana. By default I can only see Kibana fields like

```
_source, 
_index,
 _id, 
_type
```

I want all these fields to be displayed.

Comment: Actually...I am dealing with template.json file in elasiticsearch which includes the setting about mapping of data. I am able to generate these fields by mentioning them in mapping file and is visible in kibana but I am unable to push data in these fields. I cannot figure out how to do that. Kibana shows these fields as hidden fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use the Morphline interceptor in Flume to parse your data or write your own interceptor which does the job.

Logstash also works very well but it lacks the transactional capabilities of Flume.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/products/logstash).

Logstash take care of indexing many types of logs. You can find [here](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash) an example of indexing HTTP logs with the `grok`filter.

If the Logstash indexation is succefull you will be able to see all logs in Kibana.

Comment: yaa...I know about logstash...but I have been asked to use Elasticsearch.. :(